# How should I paint around my newly hung doors?

Tags: doors, interior, repainting

I just replaced my old doors with some new pre-hung ones.

Taking out the old ones ripped some of the thick paint off. Also, in some cases, the new trim doesn't reach to where the old trim was, so there is a gap that needs to be painted.

My main concern is how think my existing paint job was. It tears off like paper. Can I simply paint over it? I would HATE to TEAR my existing paint off, and repaint my ENTIRE HOUSE!

Here is the picture where my old paint meets my new doors.

[image]

Comment: Looks like water damage. The paint will peel until you reach an unaffected area. You'll have to decide where to stop picking at it and patch\paint or soon you will be redoing the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like someone didn't clean the wall adequately, and/or didn't apply primer, before the previous coat of paint. If it doesn't adhere well, paint can flake or peel off.

However, if there isn't evidence of that the problem is propagating outward, I'd say the answer is just to do the touch-up properly: Clean with a mild degreaser, apply a good quality primer, and paint in matching color.

(The good news is that you can take one of those torn-off pieces into a paint store and say "match this color"....)

Answer (score 1):

First you can use your old trim on new doors - which is more often the case after installing prehung.  Your trim should be uniform throughout a floor or house.

Also on the paint that came off.  You need to skim that with drywall mud or spackle.  Then sand it to match rest of wall, prime it and then paint whatever color you had before.